# How to make a digital clock app widget? Is a service really necessary?

Tags: android, clock, android-appwidget

I am trying to make a home screen app widget that is simply a digital clock displaying the current time.

Suprisingly the [DigitalClock view is not supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) for widgets but the AnalogClock view is.  Ive been doing a bit of research and it seems I have have to use a service.  This seems a bit like overkill for just a digital clock.

Does anyone have any suggestions or links for making a digital clock app widget?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like [24clock](http://24clock.googlecode.com)?

Market link: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alfray.a24clock 
Google Code link: http://24clock.googlecode.com

Feel free to ask any question about the code. Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This does technically answer the question, but provides mostly links. Could you elaborate on this a bit so this answer is useful on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). See http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/app-widget-using-alarm-manager.html for an example.